# using if else statements over multiple rows

Tags: r, if-statement, row

lets say i have a df

```
data111 <- structure(list(`1` = c(20.47039, 21.94899, 22.96345, 23.61655, 
24.50835, 25.92349, 26.34687, 27.83433), `2` = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("no", "p", "xa", "xae", 
"xei", "xoe"), class = "factor"), `3` = c(20.65273, 22.0617, 
23.06622, 23.68949, 24.57134, 26.01042, 26.44185, 27.93414)), .Names = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

how do i make it so i can use an if else statement over rows where a new column is populated and it takes the difference between the (i+1) and (i) row if a specific condition is met? for example:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data111)) {

      if (data111$def[i] == data111$def[i+1]) {
            data111$new <- data111$ghi[i+1] - data111$ghi[i]
      }
      else {
            data111$new <- 0
      }
}
```

this isn't working..  the new columns should have rows 1,5,6,7,8 = 0, and rows 2,3,4 equal to the difference in the 3rd column (i.w. row 2 new column = difference between row 3 column 2 - row 2 column 2)

Comment: there are no columns named "def" "ghi" or "new"

Comment: sorry - this is in R... names(data111) <- c("abc","def","ghi")  needs to be added after defining DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do with the last element, so I just kept it as is

```
#set up our i and i+1 vectors for the column def
ithDef<-data111$def[1:(nrow(data111)-1)]
i_plus_1Def<-data111$def[2:(nrow(data111))]

##set up our i and i+1 vectors for the column ghi
ithGhi<-data111$ghi[1:(nrow(data111)-1)]
i_plus_1Ghi<-data111$ghi[2:(nrow(data111))]

#the last element has no i+1, so I keep the last element the same
newNew<-c(ifelse(ithDef==i_plus_1Def, i_plus_1Ghi-ithGhi, 0), df$new[nrow(df)])
```